# GLM model with regularization

Tags: python-3.x, glm, statsmodels

I am building a GLM model (Poisson familty) and since I have a lot of features, I need to do some sort of regularization. Apparently, stats model supports regularization for some of the families in GLM model including poisson. These what I have used:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model as sm_glm
 . . 
poisson_model = sm_glm.GLM(y, X, family=sm.families.Poisson()) 
poisson_results = poisson_model.fit_regularized()
```

However, I get the error "'GLM' object has no attribute 'fit_regularized'" Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score -2):

In your code, change "sm_glm.GLM" to "sm.GLM". In my code, this method works.

Comment: It will be helpful if you explain your code change and why it is required.